What does "the muskrats" mean?
In midst of battle with Russian Tsar Alexander, Napoleon writes
a letter to his former wife Josephine:

[Napoleon] I hear the muskrats are agitated in Paris
at the idea of the emperor's return. The coward, Tsar Alexander,
now knows what I'm capable of. Who else can move half a million men
everywhere in Europe? Now a farmer boy knows that he can become a
marshal of the empire.

What does "the muskrats" mean ?
This scene from Napoleon (2023) Directors cut.

@JamesK I edited the question.

It's not a common or standard use of the word.  It's probably an insulting way to describe some type of people in Paris.  (muskrats in Europe are invasive pests).  There may be a historical reason for this choice of word, but the details are beyond this native speaker of English.  I just understand that Napoleon is being rude about some people in Paris.

In particular, the muskrat was not introduced (accidentally) to Europe until about 100 years after this movie was set, so it's not at all clear if there is any real historical meaning or just a insult, perhaps playing on "musketeer + rat"

@JamesK - I took my seat expecting a masterful take on French history. Instead, we got an industrial-grade sex-and-battles disaster ... Ridley Scott meeting his Waterloo on the screen is not a pretty sight. His Napoleon inspires in the French viewer a festival of emotions in quick succession: sadness to witness such a colossal missed opportunity; excruciating pain to hear such inept dialogue; bewilderment upon realising that Scott doesn’t seem to have bothered to pick up one history book to check, well, historical facts Agnès Poirier (Guardian)

However.. Vanessa Kirby as Josephine is the only redeeming feature in this industrial disaster of a film (ibid.)

@JamesK An anachronism in a Hollywood film? Never!

@Barmar - I suppose a film by Ridley Scott (a Briton), shot in England, Malta, and Morocco, and starring Joaquin Phoenix (an American) and financed by Sony might be termed a 'Hollywood film'. I laughed at this: the film shows Napoleon's forces taking pot-shots at the Pyramids (which never happened!) Scott defended this as being "a fast way of saying Napoleon took Egypt". Yup. Hollywood. Or Pinewood.

Ridley Scott is 86 (as Private Eye might put it). 87 next month.

It's fairly common to use animals as insults:  "He's a snake",  "The pigs are coming!" etc. "Rats" are a pest, and so have a strong negative association. If you call someone a "rat" you mean they are a cheat and a traitor.
Using "muskrat" is not common. I can't find any evidence of this being based on anything historical. It's possibly a pun on "musketeer" (mousquetaire et rat-musqué) or just a generic insult "smelly rats".  It appears to refer to people in Paris - perhaps Napoleon's political enemies.
